# Arduino Pro Micro - switch off LEDs

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

I am using a Arduino Pro Micro as a keyboard (USB HID device). Each time I press a key, the RX LED and TX LED light up. Can I switch them off in software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kind of.

You don't have to change `pins_arduino.h`.
Try the `LED_BUILTIN_TX` and the `LED_BUILTIN_RX`.
The pins are turned on and off by the code for the SerialUSB port. That can not be changed without changing the Arduino libraries. Setting that pin to INPUT in your sketch in the setup() function will turn them off:

```
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN_TX,INPUT);
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN_RX,INPUT);
```

If you have troubles with the `LED_BUILTIN_TX` and the `LED_BUILTIN_RX`, then you can use this as well:

```
bitClear(DDRD,5);
bitClear(DDRB,0);
```

The code for the SerialUSB port still writes to that pin, but once they are set as INPUT, that code will turn on and off the pullup resistor. That is no problem since those leds are connected to VCC.

To turn them on is also possible, but then those pins needs to be OUTPUT and LOW. They will **not** stay on when the SerialUSB port is used.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of.

You would need to edit the `pins_arduino.h` file for the Pro Micro board to change the definitions of the `TXLED0`, `TXLED1`, `RXLED0`, `RXLED1` and `TX_RX_LED_INIT` macros.

You want them to all be defined, but empty.

```
#undef TXLED0
#undef TXLED1
#undef RXLED0
#undef RXLED1
#undef TX_RX_LED_INIT

#define TXLED0
#define TXLED1
#define RXLED0
#define RXLED1
#define TX_RX_LED_INIT
```

That will remove the current definitions, and then create new empty definitions.  Without the empty definitions, you will get errors when compiling.